# promise.all doesn't return actual results

Tags: dictionary, asynchronous, mongoose, promise, async-await

I have this code:

```
  let result = programBenef.map(async item => {
    const beneficiary = await Beneficiary.findById(item.beneficiary_id);
    delete item.beneficiary_id;
    return {
      ...item,
      ...beneficiary
    };
  });

  result = await Promise.all(result);

console.log(result);
```

and when I do console.log(result) I have this result:

```
  Promise {
    { '$__': [InternalCache],
      isNew: false,
      errors: undefined,
      _doc: [Object],
      '$init': true } },
  Promise {
    { '$__': [InternalCache],
      isNew: false,
      errors: undefined,
      _doc: [Object],
      '$init': true } }
```

Why doesn't it return the actual result, And how to solve it?

EDIT 1: 
This is the whole function:

```
router.get("/getProgramDistr/:id", auth, async (req, res) => {
  if (req.user.roles === 1) return res.status(403);
  if (!req.params.id) return res.status(400);

  const admin_id = req.user.father_id || req.user._id;
  const programDistr = await ProgramDistributor.find({
    admin_id,
    program_id: req.params.id
  });
  if (!programDistr) return res.status(404);

  let result = await programDistr.map(async item => {
    const beneficiary = await Distributor.findById(item.distributor_id);
    delete item.distributor_id;
    return {
      ...item,
      ...beneficiary
    };
  });

  result = await Promise.all(result);

  // console.log(result, "this is the result");

  return res.send(result);
});
```

I've tried to use `for loop` instead of map and push the promises to an array then call `Promise.all(array)` and still the same outcome.

Comment: where are you calling this function? Please show the wrapping function also.

Comment: I have updated the post with the whole function

Comment: It looks like you are logging the `result` *before* awaiting and assigning the result of the `Promise.all` call. I'd suggest to use two different variables for the arrays of promises and the array of identifiers, just to make sure you didn't mess up there.

Comment: Btw, the `await` on the array returned by `programDistr.map(…)` is totally superfluous, you should drop it. (It shouldn't do any harm though, like lead to the weird log that you claim to get).

Comment: If I did understand you, I've removed the await from in front of programDistr.map(...) and assigned the result of Promise.all() to a different variable and logged that variable But still the same problem @Bergi

Comment: Then something really weird is going on. What is `Promise.all`, is it a native function? Are you using a transpiler and polyfills? Those objects don't exactly look like native promises usually returned by an `async function`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be the solution that you're looking for

```
const promises = programDistr.map(async item => Distributor.findById(item.beneficiary_id).lean() );

const results = await Promise.all(promises);

return res.send(results);
```

**breakdown**

---

`programDistr.map(async item => Distributor.findById(item.beneficiary_id).lean() );`
This returns an array of promises that will query the database for the Distributor with the matching beneficiary_id.
`lean()` is a mongoose query to just return the raw documents (which I *believe* you're going for **and** will omit your last call to `map` to the `_doc` objects). [mongoose lean documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/lean.html)

`await Promise.all(promises)`
waits for all of the queries to complete and returns into `results` variable.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I changed the code to become something like this:

```
  const result = programDistr.map(async item => {
    const distributor = await Distributor.findById(item.beneficiary_id);
    delete item.beneficiary_id;
    return {
      ...item,
      ...distributor
    };
  });

  const outcome = await Promise.all(result);

  let resss = outcome.map(item => {
    return item._doc;
  });

  return res.send(resss);
```

The outcome still gives me a weird looking array with an object in each of array's indexes, but when iterating over the array and get the value of item._doc's key I found the actual results.

But still, why can't the promise.all() return the actual result?

Comment: My answer below describes the issue you're facing. Mongoose has a built in method called `lean` which solves the problem :)  
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/lean.html